# Java NIO Отправка пакета

Tags: java

Пакеты вроде и отправляются, но сервер никак не реагирует, что я не так делаю?

Метод отправки пакета

```
public void sendPacket(Packet packet) {
    ByteBuffer tempBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2048);

    tempBuf.clear();
    buffer.clear();

    NetBufOut tempOut = new NetBufOut(tempBuf);
    packet.onWrite(tempOut);

    tempBuf.flip();

    int id = getProtocol().getId(packet.getClass(), subprotocol);

    NetBufOut out = new NetBufOut(buffer);
    out.writeVarInt(tempBuf.array().length + 1);
    out.writeVarInt(id);
    out.writeBytes(tempBuf.array());
    System.out.println(new String(tempBuf.array()));
    buffer.flip();

    try {
        while (out.getByteBuffer().hasRemaining()) {
            getChannel().write(out.getByteBuffer());

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (PacketAdapter adapter : adapters) {
        adapter.onPacketSend(packet);
    }
}
```

Формат пакетов:
[image: Формат пакета]

Может кто нибудь и разбирается в протоколе Minecraft

Описание параметров пакета Handshake
[image: Handshake packet]

```
@Override
public void onWrite(NetBufOut out) {
    out.writeVarInt(this.protocolVersion);
    out.writeString(this.host);
    out.writeShort(this.port);
    out.writeVarInt(this.nextState);
}
```

[image: LoginStartPacket]

```
@Override
public void onWrite(NetBufOut out) {
    out.writeString(this.username);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот фикс, может понадобится кому

```
public void sendPacket(Packet packet) {
    if (!isConnected())
        return;

    ByteBuffer tempBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

    tempBuf.clear();

    NetBufOut tempOut = new NetBufOut(tempBuf);

    int id = getProtocol().getId(packet.getClass(), subprotocol);

    tempOut.writeVarInt(id);

    packet.onWrite(tempOut);

    byte[] bytesToSend = trim(tempBuf.array());

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytesToSend.length + 2);
    NetBufOut out = new NetBufOut(buffer);

    out.writeVarInt(bytesToSend.length);
    out.writeBytes(bytesToSend);
    buffer.flip();

    try {
        while (out.getByteBuffer().hasRemaining()) {
            getChannel().write(out.getByteBuffer());

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (PacketAdapter adapter : adapters) {
        adapter.onPacketSend(packet);
    }
}
```

trim()

```
static byte[] trim(byte[] bytes) {
    int i = bytes.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && bytes[i] == 0) {
        --i;
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(bytes, i + 1);
}
```